# Need to find most recent file from 1 of 2 sources then copy it

Tags: powershell

OK so back again with similar but  different issue than yesterday, need to search directory and grab ONLY the most recent

```
$source =  "\\serverA\path\file*.txt"
$source2 =  "\\serverB\path\file*.txt"
$destination = "\\serverX\path\file.txt"
IF (Test-Path $source)
{
    Get-ChildItem $source | ForEach-Object
    {
        sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -first 1 |Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination
    }
}
ELSE
{
    IF (Test-Path $source2)
    {
        Get-ChildItem $source2 | ForEach-Object
        {
            sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -first 1 |Copy-Item -Path $source2 -Destination $destination
        } 
    }
}
```

The above runs in a second, should copy a 500 MB file but it throws no errors

Comment: What does it *do*? Does it copy zero files? Does it copy the *wrong* file? Does it *move* the file instead of *copying* it? Does it plaster cat pictures all over Facebook?

Comment: Does nothing, just goes back to prompt after a second

Comment: No  empty files, no cat pics, nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$sources =  "\\serverA\path\file*.txt", "\\serverB\path\file*.txt" 
$destination = "\\serverX\path\file.txt"

$sources | where { Test-Path $_ } | % {gci -Path $_ -File} | sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

Comment: Thanks this was most like the direction I was going / wanted to go

Answer (score 2):

In this section you are doing a `foreach` loop, passing in individual objects to `sort`.

```
Get-ChildItem $source | ForEach-Object {
    sort LastWriteTime -desc
```

Instead you want to sort the whole collection:

```
Get-ChildItem $source | sort LastWriteTime -desc
```

And here you are piping in an object but still declaring the Path:

```
|Copy-Item -Path $source
```

Clearing those two issues up, the first if block would look something like this:

```
IF (Test-Path $source) {
    Get-ChildItem $source | sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -first 1 | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Invoke-Command can be used.
or, map a PSDrive to the server, and then run the command locally against that drive

Comment: Using Invoke-Command command to then do a Copy-Item gets into the two-hop problem, complicating the issue.